# Re-vamp an old design, replacing background images with new CSS3 rules

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-shapes

I have to re-vamp a 3 years old website mantaining substuntially the same look&feel while upgrading coding technologies with extensive CSS3 techniques, to make it modern and responsive.

This was a design that used transparency, emboss and cutted areas, *originally crated in Photoshop, and then coded using background tile images cutted from original one*.

A detail, that synthetizes challenges to solve is shown here:

[image]

Here the the key topics:

1. Header has a semi-transparent background that shows the body's one, but has also 3D-look borders with an horizontal gradient from left to right.
2. Header's background (and its borders) has also an emboss look with light and shadows in upper-left and down-right corners.
3. Logo and site name are over the header background in a cutted area.

Here, **my actual WIP to re-create this with only CSS3**:

[image]

As you can see, are still missing, **emboss-effect**, **border-gradients** and above all..... **logo cutted area** (for the moment I simply placed over an image, taken by original layout).

Can you help me to get the most similar result to original one?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide part of your html and css?

Comment: Besides, have you considered using [SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)?

Comment: for what you are trying to achieve, either an svg or image would still (probably) be the way to go. In order to generate that in css, I can only think of using multiple elements (of which It would still be hacky). Esp if you were looking cross browser compatibility as well as gradient borders

Comment: I thought about SVG images but sincerely I did not figure out how to use them. In details, what details do you suggest to render via an svg image? More important..... some ideas about "cutted logo area" ? how to achieve it?

Comment: I like what you're attempting to do but I've got to ask: why? If the logo is a fixed size anyway then I don't see any benefit to using CSS / CVG methods. In fact, you'll still end up needing your original image to provide support to older browsers anyway.

Comment: SVG is supported since IE9, support for IE8 could be lacked and, in my intension, warned by a popup that informs user about old browser in use. :-) anyway, your objection about static nature of logo is real and correct, maybe I should combine approach suggested by Tim Krul in his answer with traditional DIV background...

Comment: You can try Raphael by Dmitry. It uses VML as a fallback for IE8 and below, and can surely help improve browser support. Though I think there aren't many people using IE 8- :-)

Comment: Sincerely I would like to leave logo and brand as transparent png image, while replacing the blue-green bordered region (thay you recreate in svg) with a vector version, in order to reduce KBs and make a step into 21th century of web :-D

Comment: @LucaDetomi - except you now need two images for the backdrop and the logo instead of just one. You're probably adding more KBs and certainly more server requests. Again, I like the idea in principle but I don't think this is the best place to try and do it. I look forward to seeing what answers you get though!

Comment: @JohnReid: thanks!!! I surely consider your opinion. I'll try, it's a good exercise :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can create the shape using SVG paths :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="110" width="600" viewBox="4 4 92 16">
    <path d="M 5 6 a 1 1 0 0 1 1 -1 h 14 a 4.2 4.2 0 0 0 8 0 h1 a 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 h 49 a 1 1 0 0 0 1 -1 h14 a 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 v 10 a 1 1 0 0 1 -1 1 h -88 a 1 1 0 0 1 -1 -1z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.6" />
</svg>
```

To this basic shape, you can fill gradients, photos, etc.

Comment: thank you so much.... I'll try it asap. Just to know, how did you create this path? some tool that vectorize my image, or something else?

Comment: I finally tried to implement this solution but it shows many limits (maybe because I don't know it very well). For example, I am unable to extend this image to fill the entire DIV container (even changing viewBox attribute), or manage it in a Responsive way, reducing its width but leaving height and borders-width unchanged. Does exist a way to improve this solution?

Comment: i guess u should try width: 100%; in styles associated with the rqrd svg element

Answer (score 0):

For the emboss you can use an inset [box shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), or a background with a [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) value.

For the gradient border you can use the [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) property with a [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) value.

For the "logo cutted area" an idea would be to use a positioned parent div with a border radius and a matching gradient background.

Comment: inset box-shadow maybe could be the best solution, while border-image is compatible only from IE11 or above.... yes, maybe I could provide a simple solid color fallback for IE10 and below... :-)